# Regex in array or hash - sorting

Tags: ruby, regex, arrays

I have a work folder directory.

```
holder = Dir.glob("*")
=> holder = ["Project One", "Project Two", "Project Three", "Backups", "Summer 2012"]
```

I would like to use regex in my script to sort a new file that is in another directory into one of the Project directories above. I can easily do this using a `regex.match` command like.

```
other_files = ["Project One Picture 2399.jpg", "Project Two Doc.txt"]
if /project\Done/i.match(other_files[0])
#if true cp to Project One directory i think you get the point
```

I would like to create regex expression from the `holder` array. So all i need to do is create another folder and the script will add another regex in the array. Is there an easy way to do this? Or is there a way to store regex in an array?

```
regex_array = ["/project\Done/i", "/project\Dtwo/i", "/project\Dthree/i", "/backups/i", "/summer\W\d\d\d\d/i"]
```

Comment: It is not clear.. you are saying lot's of things,but none of them are so specific ..what are you trying to do ?

Comment: This program monitors two folders. One folder has other folders `holder` and the other has the files `other_files` I want to make a program that dynamically creates regex from the `holder` array so i can sort `other_files` into the correct `holder` folder.

Comment: Why *"Backups", "Summer 2012"* are not included in the array `regex_array` ?

Comment: should be, i'll fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regexp.new creates a new regex:

```
Regexp.new 'your expression'
# => /your expression/
```

You can push these onto your regex_array. You can store them as regexes, not strings.

```
regex_array = holder.map {|folder| Regexp.new(folder.downcase, Regexp::IGNORECASE) }
# => [/project one/i, /project two/i, /project three/i]
```

Comment: This shouldn't be an issue, but is there a way to make it read. `=> [/project\Done/i, /project\Dtwo/i, /project\Dthree/i]`

Comment: `regex_array = holder.map {|folder| Regexp.new(folder.downcase.gsub(' ', '\D'), Regexp::IGNORECASE) }`

Answer (score 0):

You could skip regex_array with something like this:

```
holder = ["Project One", "Project Two", "Project Three", "Backups", "Summer 2012"]
other_files = ["Project One Picture 2399.jpg", "Project Two Doc.txt"]
other_files.each do |f|
  dir = holder.find {|d| f =~ /#{d}/i} 
  # copy file f to dir if dir
end
```

...though you might want a more elaborate regex.